# How to stop $.ajax within for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm running into an issue where my api call reaches it's timeout limit, but continues to loop for the remainder of the requests provided resulting in `n` number of timeout logs in the console (In this case 5). I want it so that I can do something along the lines of a `break;` and just exit entirely so the remaining calls don't get logged. E.g. If the call immediately times out, only one timeout log will be logged instead of the current 5 and none of the five api requests will be made.

```
let qs = {
    requests: 5,
    timeout: 1000
};
let prices = [];
let highest = 0;

const url = 'http://somedata.com';

function xhr(qs){
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: qs.timeout,
        success: function (data) {
            let json = JSON.stringify(data['price']);
            prices.push(json);
            getHighestPrice(prices);
            console.log(highest);
        },
        error: function(e, textstatus, message) {
            if(textstatus==="timeout") {
                console.error(textstatus);
            } else {
                console.error(textstatus);
            }
        }
    });
}

function makeRequest(qs) {
    for(let i = 0; i < qs.requests; i++) {
        xhr(qs);
    }
}

function getHighestPrice(arr) {
    for(let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > highest) {
            highest = arr[i]
        }
    }

    return highest;
}

makeRequest(qs);
```

Comment: `break` wont help as all the requests are started immediately - you may want to look into abort

Comment: That works in part when I tried it. It aborts the current request, but not subsequent ones.

Comment: "that works" ... what does? your code makes no attempt to abort anything

Comment: do you understand that using your code all five requests will always be started? Is that a problem? did you only want to make request 2 if request 1 succeeds, 3 if 2 succeeds etc, or do you want to make the 5 requests, but only log the first timeout?

Comment: Exactly. You hit the nail on the head. "make request 2 if request 1 succeeds." I didn't explain well.

Comment: @jaromanda-x is there a way to not make all of the calls?

Comment: There are two answers so far that will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes all the requests at once

It should be noted that this code will stop the "chaining" once **any** error occurs in `$.ajax`, not just timeout - if that's not the required behaviour, there is a little more to do

To make the call only if the previous is successful, you can chain the promises returned by $.ajax

```
let qs = {
    requests: 5,
    timeout: 1000
};
let prices = [];
let highest = 0;
function xhr(qs){
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: qs.timeout,
        success: function (data) {
            let json = JSON.stringify(data['price']);
            prices.push(json);
            getHighestPrice(prices);
            console.log(highest);
        },
        error: function(e, textstatus, message) {
            if (textstatus==="timeout") {
                console.error(textstatus);
            } else {
                console.error(textstatus);
            }
        }
    });
}

function makeRequest(qs) {
    let p = $.when();
    for(let i = 0; i < qs.requests; i++) {
        p = p.then(() => xhr(qs));
    }
}
```

> as others have pointed out you don't need to pass `qs` to `xhr`, however, I'm assuming the code you posted may be simplified so have not removed the `qs` argument

An alternative would be

```
let qs = {
    requests: 5,
    timeout: 1000
};
let prices = [];
let highest = 0;
function xhr(qs){
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: qs.timeout
    }).then(data => {
        let json = JSON.stringify(data['price']);
        prices.push(json);
        getHighestPrice(prices);
        console.log(highest);
    });
}

function makeRequest(qs) {
    let p = $.when([]);
    for(let i = 0; i < qs.requests; i++) {
        p = p.then(() => xhr(qs));
        // or p.then(xhr); if you don't need to pass qs on to xhr function (remove qs argument in xhr as well)
    }
    p.then(() => {
        // this is run once all have completed
    }).fail(reason => {
        // this is run if there's a failure anywhere
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know `$.when`

Comment: `$.when()` is like (but not exactly like) `Promise.resolve()` - jQuery has it's own "vision" of Promises, that are a little removed from Promise/A+ spec

Comment: Cool, I'll look into that, I didn't know jQuery had their own.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a callback, it will be executed asynchronously. So even if you throw an error from one of the callback you provided, the rest will be executed later or sooner. One of the solution I could think of is to have a flag that will be set to true if one of the AJAX causes an error. Something like:

```
var hasError = false;
$.ajax({
  error: function (e, textstatus, message) {
    if (textstatus === "timeout") {
      if (!hasError) console.error(textstatus);
      hasError = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This just makes it so it doesn't log multiple times. The calls and logs are still being made unfortunately.   Jaromanda X explained it best. If the first request succeeds and the second doesn't,  the remaining three calls are not made.

Comment: I thought that was what you asked. **" E.g. If the call immediately times out, only one timeout log will be logged instead of the current 5."** Please be more specific and clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Using Promise.all() can simplify this use case. If you cannot use promises try throwing an exception from the error handler. Like so:

```
$.ajax({
    error: function (e, textstatus, message) {
        if (textstatus === "timeout") throw e
    }
})
```

Be sure to catch the the exception:

```
function makeRequest(qs) {
    try {
        for(let i = 0; i < qs.requests; i++) {
            xhr(qs);
        }
    } catch (e) { // Handle error here }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just implemented it, but it still logs out 5 errors.

Comment: this doesn't address the question at all

Comment: I think it's because it's a race condition. If I log out the `i` in the loop above `xhr(qs)`, 1,2,3,4,5 all log out before the errors from the catch

Comment: Can you post a sample jsbin? Throw will most definitely stop the loop.

Comment: no it wont @rapta, because ALL requests are initiated before any have the chance to timeout - the loop is finished before the first request has a chance to timeout

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired behavior you will have to make all of the calls sequentially i.e. you can't start the next call until the previous one has finished (otherwise you won't know if it has failed or not).

You could use the `done` callback to determine whether the next call should be made:

```
  function makeRequest(i) {
    xhr().done(function(){
      if (i < qs.requests){
        makeRequest(i+1)
      }
    })
  }

  makeRequest(0); // Kick things off here
```

Also, you don't need to pass the `qs` variable into the `makeRequest` or `xhr` functions. It doesn't change throughout the calls so just use it as-is within the `xhr` function without passing it around.

Comment: Good call out on the passing of qs

Comment: @tim Pleased to contribute that small part if nothing else. Does this not provide the desired behavior?

Comment: Maybe I need to do more, but I'm getting a `success is not a function of xhr()` when I implement this.

Comment: corrrect, success is NOT a function of the object returned by $.ajax ... perhaps it should be `.done` or `.then` instead

Comment: @JaromandaX Correct! It should be `done`. Silly mistake sorry, thanks for correcting me.